# Handling .csv files that starts with "sep= " at the begining using Pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv with tab delimited file that looks like below when you open with Notepad (the space you see in Notepad is actually tab (\t):

```
sep = 
Time Val1 Val2
00:01 10 20
```

"sep=" is there so that excel can read the .csv file correctly. The problem is that when you try to open it using read_csv, it returns a single column dataframe with column named "s". If I open the file with Excel and double click the first column width to have auto width, save and close, then the file is correctly formatted to comma delimit. No more "sep=" at the beginning of the file when you open with Notepad, and then Pandas reads it correctly with all the columns and values.

Before anyone asks:
1. I tried to remove first line using:

```
with open(csvFileName, mode="rU") as infile:
with open(csvFileName, mode="r") as infile:
```

to either remove the first line, or replace "\t" with "," and write it back to another file, all did not work. 
2. I also tried to detect and use different encoding schemes, so encoding is not the problem. 
3. The file uses `lineterminator = \n`, and I use that parameter to read
4. I use `skiprows=0` to skip the first row, didnt work
5. I tried to set `header = 1` to point it to the line that it has header, and set `sep=\t`, it reads the number of columns and rows correctly, but column names are "UnnamedXYZ" and values are all `NaNs`

Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the separator value from the first line to parse the csv:

input from data.csv:

```
  sep = ,
  Year Dec Jan
     1  50  60
     2  25  50
     3  30  30
     4  40  20
     5  10  10
```

Read file into list, and save into dataframe:

```
x = []
sep = ''
with open(filename) as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 0:
            sep = line.rstrip()[-1]
        if i > 0:
            x.append(line.rstrip().split(','))
x = pd.DataFrame(data=x[1:], columns=x[0])
```

x

```
  Year Dec Jan
0    1  50  60
1    2  25  50
2    3  30  30
3    4  40  20
4    5  10  10
```

You should add further logic to handle if there is no separator or if the separator field is empty, or if the separator does not exist in the subsequent rows of the csv.

Comment: That works, thanks! Just need a small tweak to replace the ',' with `sep` in the `split`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) use skiprows.

> skiprowslist-like, int or callable, optional
>
> ```
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False
> ```
>
> otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x in [0, 2].